# Highlight after searching multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba

This question is long.
I have SKUs in 12 tables in say sheet1, and the table header is the material required for that product.
I have a list of materials required on a seperate sheet (Sheet2).
I have created a dropdown for the SKUs in Sheet2 which highlights the material required for that SKU.

A single SKU can occur in multiple tables.
I have taken this approach because it was easier to update the SKUs in the tables than the materials required.

I have already made a code for highlighting the material required, and this code already runs whenever I select SKU from the drop down.

**I would like the following code to search in multiple tables for the same SKU highlight all the materials required for that SKU.
Can this be done?**

Any suggestion and help is greatly appreciated as I have searched a lot for something similar.

Below is the code for highlight:

```
Sub Hilight(RNG As range, Hilight As Boolean)
        With RNG.Interior
            If Hilight Then
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = RGB(100, 250, 150)
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            Else
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

And here is How I have been using this `Sub`

```
Dim L8Product As String
Dim L11Product As String
Dim L12Product As String
Dim L10Product As String
Dim i As Long
Dim L8Rnge As range
Dim L11Rnge As range
Dim L12Rnge As range
Dim L10Rnge As range

L11Product = range("Line11_P")
L12Product = range("Line12_P")
L10Product = range("Line10_P")
L8Product = range("Line8_P")

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.range("Line8_P, Line11_P, Line12_P, Line10_P")) Is Nothing Then
        Hilight range("Line8_Hilight_Mon, Line8_Prep_Mon, Line11_Hilight_Mon, Line12_Hilight_Mon, Line10_Hilight_Mon"), False
'Below Code searches in the Table and then highlights the appropriate cells
    If Trim(L8Product) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Products").range("KP_Table")                     'searchs in the KP Table on Sheet Overtime_Pos_Table

            'The code below will search the KP table for the product that you will select from the Line 8 drop down
            Set L8Rnge = .Find(what:=L8Product, _
                            after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                            searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not L8Rnge Is Nothing Then
                    Hilight range("KP_Hilight_Mon, Line8_Prep_Mon"), True               'Hilights the cells for the KP and the Prep material required
            Else: With Sheets("Products").range("Osgood_Table")
                    Set L8Rnge = .Find(what:=L8Product, _
                                    after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                    searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                                    searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not L8Rnge Is Nothing Then
                            Hilight range("Osgood_Hilight_Mon, Line8_Prep_Mon"), True   'Hilights the cells for the Osgood and the Prep material required
                    End If
                  End With
            End If
        End With
    Else: Hilight range("Line8_Hilight_Mon, Line8_Prep_Mon"), False
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @urdearboy Hi, sorry for the bad placing of the sentences. I updated the question. Hope it is clear now.